# Filter Wikipedia API link output to current content

Tags: python, json, api, nlp, wikipedia-api

I want to develop some kind of knowledge tree for some Wikipedia articles, so I am using the Wiki API to get JSON encoded data with this.

http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allpages&format=json&aplimit=10&generator=links&titles=List_of_object-oriented_programming_terms&gpllimit=10

The problem is, it seems to be an outdated version or I need to use a different option because I get different information than what the current Browser show for the same article.

This so disgusting because I am getting literally "F*ck you's" in the output (THIS IS SERIOUS visit the link if you don't believe). Example:

```
[
    {"pageid":5878274,"ns":0,"title":"!"},
    {"pageid":3632887,"ns":0,"title":"!!"},
    {"pageid":600744,"ns":0,"title":"!!!"},
    {"pageid":34443176,"ns":0,"title":"!!!Dam You!!!"},
    {"pageid":11011780,"ns":0,"title":"!!!Dam You!!! And Then Some"},
    {"pageid":34443184,"ns":0,"title":"!!!Dam You!!! and Then Some"},
    {"pageid":2556962,"ns":0,"title":"!!! (album)"},
    {"pageid":10065458,"ns":0,"title":"!!! (band)"},
    {"pageid":16381751,"ns":0,"title":"!!Destroy-Oh-Boy!!"},
    {"pageid":16789001,"ns":0,"title":"!!Dam you!!"}
]
```

Any ideas what other approach I could use to get all the current Wikipedia articles links inside an article?

Thanks in advance. I plan to work with Python if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you may be using an option wrong.
Remove the

```
&list=allpages
```

From the URL. This returned me the right links.

See http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Query#Using_list.3Dallpages_as_generator for more information.

Comment: Thanks it works!, any idea what would be the goal of using &list=allpages without paremeters?

Wiki Api says: Enumerate all pages sequentially in a given namespace.


But I think the option (&list=allpages) should be ignored by the API if not other arguments provided like &apfrom, &apminsize, etc...

Comment: From the link I gave, list=allpages overrules the titles option no matter what parameters you give. That's just the way the API is. Since your didn't specify the beginning title, it started at the beginning: !!... You would use the list=allpages parameters to go through **every** page on the wiki.